# Firebase hosting: rewrite rule failing when there is no trailing slash

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting two SPAs (that are built separately) in Firebase Hosting. My build process generates a directory structure like this:

```
/build
|
|-- index.html
|-- scripts.js
|-- style.css
|
|--- /app
     |
     |-- index.html
     |-- scripts.js
     |-- style.css
```

If I connect my domain, `example.com`, I would like `https://example.com` to serve the first SPA and `https://example.com/app` to serve the second SPA.

Also, I would like that every address of the form `https://example.com/xxx` was rewritten to `https://example.com/index.html` if the file doesn't exist and, similarly, everything pointing to `https://example.com/app/xxx`was rewritten to `https://example.com/app/index.html`.

I managed to make it work with the following configuration:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "app/**",
        "destination": "/app/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but now, when I go to `https://example.com/app` **WITHOUT SLASH**, it serves the "root" SPA. If I instead go to `https://example.com/app/` **WITH SLASH**, it serves the "nested" SPA as it should.

How can I make `https://example.com/app` serve the "nested" SPA?

**WHAT I TRIED**

- Setting `trailingSlash` to `true` and `false`, respectively. No change. (see docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config))
- Setting a 301 redirect in the configuration from `https://example.com/app` to `https://example.com/app/`. The site dies in my Chrome with `Too many redirects`.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do this with a single rewrite rule.

You'll need to add two rewrites, one for `app`, and another for `app/`.

```json
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "/app",
        "destination": "/app/index.html"
    },
    {
        "source": "/app/**",
        "destination": "/app/index.html"
    },
    {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way:

```
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "/api{,/**}",
  // destination | run | function
}]
```